# (linux) jupyter notebook cites file : permission denied

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, directory

I'm running alphafold.

My jupyter notebook wants to visit a file, and shows 'permission denied'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2436/4236937636.py in <cell line: 129>()
    136   # Don't do redundant work for multiple copies of the same chain in the multimer.
    137   if sequence not in raw_msa_results_for_sequence:
--> 138     raw_msa_results = get_msa(fasta_path=fasta_path)
    139     raw_msa_results_for_sequence[sequence] = raw_msa_results
    140   else:

/tmp/ipykernel_2436/4236937636.py in get_msa(fasta_path)
    120           z_value=db_config['z_value'])
    121       # Group the results by database name.
--> 122       raw_msa_results[db_name].extend(jackhmmer_runner.query(fasta_path))
    123 
    124   return raw_msa_results

~/Alphafold/alphafold/alphafold/data/tools/jackhmmer.py in query(self, input_fasta_path, max_sequences)
    198         # Run Jackhmmer with the chunk
    199         future.result()
--> 200         chunked_output.append(self._query_chunk(
    201             input_fasta_path, db_local_chunk(i), max_sequences))
    202 

~/Alphafold/alphafold/alphafold/data/tools/jackhmmer.py in _query_chunk(self, input_fasta_path, database_path, max_sequences)
    132 
    133       logging.info('Launching subprocess "%s"', ' '.join(cmd))
--> 134       process = subprocess.Popen(
    135           cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    136       with utils.timing(

~/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
    949                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    950 
--> 951             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    952                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    953                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1819                     if errno_num != 0:
   1820                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1821                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1822                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1823 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './hmmer-3.3.1/src/'
```

l have tried to use 'chmod 777' but useless.

my trial of chmod 777

```
os.system('chmod 777 -R /home/studio-lab-user/hmmer-3.3.1/src/*')
JACKHMMER_BINARY_PATH = './hmmer-3.3.1/src/'
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: already editted, thanks